# Reset default filters for tableau view via rest api

Tags: tableau-api

I am using tableau rest api for [view data](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v10.5/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Query_View_Data%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Reference%7C_____71) to fetch data for views. There are some default filter values applied to the view filters and I am getting data filtered according to that. I want the complete data. How can I clear the filters via tableau rest api. I cannot use their javascript api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no endpoint in the rest api that enables this functionality out-of-the-box.  You may be able to download the workbook and script something that interrogates the raw xml (a twb/twbx file is simply xml) and updates the default filter(s).  You can then re-package the workbook and push back to server, then fetch the data.

If you are restricted due to row-level security rules on the data source...the above will not work.